# Laravel Nova: Group form fields in columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

How can i create columns on my form fields in Laravel Nova?

For instance, i'm trying to separate the first- and lastname but don't wanna have it on two lines. I would prefere to have it next to each other, but i don't find any possibility to choose that option.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? Or has a package that does it? I already searched but nothing found.

Thanks

Update:
The [web agency](http://treestones.ch/) guys helped me out, created a custom field.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with Laravel Nova.

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheaved with this package: https://github.com/64robots/nova-fields
And some custom CSS defined on certain fields. In my case it was like so:

```
...
->labelClasses('w-full pt-4')
->wrapperClasses('flex flex-col w-1/3 float-left flex-1 px-4 pl-8')
...
```

w-1/3 means 33%, and float-left is, of course, float: left. Apply float-left on 2 first fields, and the w-1/3 tree will result in 3 columns.

Example: [image]

Example:

`composer require 64robots/nova-fields`

```php
public function fields(Request $request) {
    return [
        ID::make('ID', 'id')->sortable(),

        \R64\NovaFields\Select::make('Order type', 'order_type')->options([
            'equipment_rent'                   => 'Equipment Rental',
            'entertainment_and_equipment_rent' => 'Entertainment and Equipment Rental',
            'equipment_rent_inplace'           => 'Equipment Rental on Location',
        ]) ->labelClasses('w-full pt-4')
           ->wrapperClasses('flex flex-col w-1/3 float-left flex-1 px-4 pl-8')
           ->fieldClasses('w-full py-4'),

        \R64\NovaFields\Select::make('Region', 'region')->options([
            'country'                          => 'Vilniaus',
            'province'                         => 'Klaipėda',
        ]) ->labelClasses('w-full pt-4')
           ->wrapperClasses('flex flex-col w-1/3 float-left flex-1 px-4')
           ->fieldClasses('w-full py-4'),

        \R64\NovaFields\BelongsTo::make('Seller', 'seller', Seller::class)
           ->labelClasses('w-full pt-4')
           ->wrapperClasses('flex flex-col w-1/3 flex-1 px-4 pr-8')
           ->fieldClasses('w-full py-4'),

        Text::make('Test'),
        Text::make('Test another'),
    ];
}
```